# How to convert time to timestamp in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i have a time input tag and when i click a button i need to get time from that input tag and convert it to timestamp. Here is my code,

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="time" class="timein"/>
<input type="button"class="convert_timestamp"/>
```

**JS code**

```
$('body').on("click",".convert_timestamp",function(){
var tm = $(".time").val();
var tmp = Date.now(tm);
});
```

We usually get current timestamp using **Date.now()** . In this case how to get a timestamp by sending a custom time. Can someone please help me with this? . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the user free to insert time in every format? In this case you shoud differentiate each case, maybe using regex...

Answer (score 4):

`var tmp = new Date(tm).getTime() // 1499072255507`

For instance :

```
new Date("2017/07/03") // Mon Jul 03 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)

new Date("2017/07/03").getTime() // 1499032800000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new Date with `new` :

```
var d = new Date(tm);
```

You can also get the timestamp using the `plus` operator which triggers the `valueOf` of the targeted object :

```
var timestamp = +d;
```

Comment: The `plus` operator is really usefull for everything regarding Integers parsing & such.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string is in the correct format the following should work

```
$('body').on("click",".convert_timestamp",function(){
    var tm = $(".time").val();
    var tmp = new Date(tm).getTime();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```js
$('.convert_timestamp').on("click",function(){
var tm = $(".timein").val();
var tmp = Date(tm);
var only_time = Date.now(tm);
console.log("time with date" ,tmp);    
console.log("only time", only_time);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="time" class="timein"/>
<input type="button" value="gen Timestamp" class="convert_timestamp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on("click",".convert_timestamp",function(){
var tm = $(".time").val();
var tmp = new Date(tm).getTime();
// now tmp contain 2165465498764 
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.